# Github Pages Not Publishing

Tags: github, github-pages

I have made my repo source a master branch and followed the instructions here: https://pages.github.com/, but I still cannot publish my site to Github pages (my index.html file is in the root). It says that "It is ready to be published", but I don't know how to actually publish it.

Comment: There is not enough information provided in your question for us to do any helpful troubleshooting (other than guessing) - Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question

Answer (score 1):

Github has had a [major outage](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18272928) over the last 24 hours. It looks like they are still recovering and some actions are delayed.

> We are working through the backlogs of webhook deliveries and **Pages builds**. We continue to monitor as the site recovers.

https://twitter.com/githubstatus/status/1054442347570839552

Comment: So this would be the reason it says "ready to publish" not "published" and why I am getting a 404 error when I got the provided link?

Comment: @barskyn Did you figure this out?